# jQuery is Commenting out my PHP Code Snippets

Tags: php, jquery, code-snippets

I'm building a code snippet system and am using jQuery to display the editor.  I noticed jQuery likes to comment out any inline PHP code.  Is there a way to prevent this from happening:

```
<textarea id='beep'></textarea>
```

jQuery code:

```
var code = "<div>Why <?php echo 'hello'; ?> there!</div>";
var parsed = $(code).html();
$('#beep').val(parsed);
```

This is what I would like to see in the textarea:

```
Why <?php echo 'hello'; ?> there!
```

But instead jQuery modifies it to look like this:

```
Why <!--?php echo 'hello'; ?--> there!
```

I understand this is probably a security measure, but is there a way to stop this from happening?

I know I can use HTML entities to get around this, but due to the nature of this tool it would interfere with code snippets being posted that intentionally include html entities.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YB4fD/1/

**Additional Node**:  Some answers suggest I use JavaScript to handle this without jQuery, but I need jQuery.  My string contains a DOM tree that I'm using jQuery to parse.

Comment: There's no relevant mention of `php`, `<?`, or `?>` in http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js.

Comment: What is wrong with `$('#beep').val("Why <?php echo 'hello'; ?> there!")`?

Comment: @Eric There is more code that I left out. I'm parsing the string as a DOM tree. Basically I need to use jQuery.

Comment: The problem is that `$(code)` tried to parse the string in `code` as HTML. `<?php echo 'hello;' ?>` is not valid HTML. jQuery does the same thing the browser would do if it received that in an HTML document, it turns it into an HTML comment.

Comment: The code you're assigning to `var code` cannot be parsed to a valid DOM tree. PHP is not HTML.

Comment: Thank you, that explains it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var code = "<div>Why &lt;?php echo 'hello'; ?&gt; there!</div>";
```

Comment: While this answer was obvious, I was trying to avoid it.  Seems this is the only choice.

Comment: Where is the original snippet data coming from? It may have a function to do this automatically for you, e.g. PHP's `htmlentities()`.

Comment: Yes, I am now using htmlentities() server-side before passing the data to jQuery to parse.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick.

```
var code = "Why <?php echo 'hello'; ?> there!";
document.getElementById('beep').appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
```

It is not valid to use other elements inside of a textarea-element.

Comment: Nor is it my intention.  I wrapped the string with a <div> in order to parse it with jQuery.  I'm looping through each element using contents().each() so this is why I need jQuery.